# Nanoc 4.7.10 and Bootstrap integration

Tags: bootstrap-4, static-site, nanoc

Does anyone have any instructions on how to integrate Bootstrap into Nanoc?

I have googled this but have not found a tutorial that would guide me through the initial integration setup.

Can anyone provide a quick walkthrough to get me started?

Comment: What kind of integration do you mean?

Comment: I want to use bootstrap  for responsive mobile support and templating like you would on a normal website.

Comment: I have no experience with Bootstrap, but can’t you just add its CSS files to Nanoc like you would add any other CSS files?